# Where is my download from iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I purchased 'Chris Hardwick Mandroid' SD Movie on iTunes.  I see it in Finder, and I see it in my Recently Added playlist... but I don't see it in my list of Movies or TV Shows on iTunes.

First Question:  Am I too big of an idiot to consume such media on my Mac?
Second Question (seriously):  Where do I find my media in iTunes?!

Answer (score 2):

From the Recently Added playlist you should be able to right-click (or ctrl-click if you don't have a right mouse button) and choose Get Info. Under the Options tab on the Get Info pane there is a choice for Media Kind. If that choice is set to Movie (as it should be) then you should be able to see it in your Movies list. Can you show the list of all things in your Movies and sort by Date Added?

Comment: Thanks for the post... after opening/closing Get Info, it showed up.  There is also now the 'Comedy' grouping for Genres.  Seems like iTunes had a mind slip and forgot to update after the download.